RAM errors with good RAM
My computer shuts down several times a day with the error windows (blue screen):

MEMORY MANAGEMENT
driver irql not less or equal
system thread exception not handled

I decided to check the RAM. And I saw the following errors:

I also have another computer with very similar specs. I checked this RAM on another computer, there are no errors. I also took the RAM from another computer and checked it on mine, it also shows errors. It seems that any RAM on my computer is showing errors.
Regardless of the errors, I can still use the computer even if the RAM is crammed to 100%. But several times a day the computer turns off with errors. I don't understand the regularities under which conditions the computer turns off, it's like randomness.
When the computer turned off for the first time, then there is a high probability that it will turn off again several times after restarting. As if he had "bad times". But then it works stably again for at least a whole day.
Computer characteristics:
System board chipset    Intel Wellsburg C612, Intel Broadwell-EP
Memory DIMM-D1: Micron 36ASF4G72PZ-2G1A1
CPU 10-Core Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4, 2200 MHz (22 x 100)
Videocard Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics  (4 GB)
What could be the problem?

If that memory channel on the CPU is faulty, it might be that you could put the RAM stick in a different socket and have a working system. I could not quickly find any information stating authoritatively that it will or will not work that way.

@AndrewMorton I tried this, the result is the same. I have 4 RAM slots. True, for some reason only 2 (orange) work, the other 2 (black) have not worked since the purchase of the motherboard.


If you are lucky then it just needs new thermal paste on the CPU (unlikely, IMHO). 2) Can you swap the processor? If it works with a different processor then you have found the problem. 3) I don't know how you would test the power supply to the RAM. 4) It could be that the black RAM slots will only work when there is RAM in the corresponding orange slot.


If you ruled out the memory being the culprit then the motherboard socket is the culprit.

@gomin1d I would go with Ramhound's ideas before mine. Does it look like there is any dirt in the RAM socket?

@AndrewMorton 1) I changed the thermal paste a month ago, all temperatures are within the normal range not higher than 60 degrees. 2) Yes, I can try another processor, thanks for the tip. 3) I don't know either 4) I wonder why it works like that?

@AndrewMorton There is no dirt. Everything is as clean as new. Also, I checked both orange slots, the result is the same.
